# Can't Install RosJava

Tags: android-core, ros-hydro, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow this rosJava installation tutorial: [here](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment)

When running catkin_make I get the following error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.2,0.3).
     Required by:
         :android_core:unspecified
```

I am using the ADT with eclipse on version 19 of the SDK.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123041/can%27t-install-rosjava/) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, they should be pointing at the hydro branches - experimental code has been going into the master branches and is not continually tested.

I updated the links on the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment) page to point to the android hydro rosinstallers.

Give them a whirl and thanks for the heads up.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0